# Nginx Drupal Redirect Loop

Tags: nginx, drupal-7

In the root of my SSL directory I have 2 separate Drupal 7 installations on the same domain name, one linked to www.eastercamp.org.nz/southern/ and one at www.eastercamp.org.nz/central/, previously running apache this all worked fine.

However now that I've moved over to Nginx (I'm still quite new to it), on my current server block config (linked below) accessing either of the above URL's ends in a redirect loop and I can't figure out why.

How do I get this working?

My Nginx server-block config file: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6761774/

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is that the URI `/central` and `/southern` are sent to your drupal installation, so the framework is looking for routes that match that, when it's not found it returns a `404` error not a redirect loop.

You need to rewrite the request uri in those paths, try adding this location block and tell me if it works

```
location /(southern|central)(?<myuri>.*) {
  rewrite ^ $myuri last;
}
```

I also think your `@rewrite` location should be modified, but we'll see if this works first or not.